# Flash AIR 3.2 Android Captive Runtime URLLoader throws stream error #2032 local file

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

The following code is a snippet of a much larger project I'm working on. The problem is when I test the app in Flash CS6 urlLoader reads 25Notes.txt perfectly but when I try debugging the app (via Flash's built in "Debug>Debug Movie>On Device via USB") on my Android device (HTC Incredible) urlLoader throws a stream error #2032.

I'm deploying the app with Captive Runtime from AIR 3.2 using Flash CS6 and my project is organized with no extraneous files or folders.

Please let me know if you have any insight or suggestions and if you need more of an explanation or code.

I'm also not sure if Captive Runtime in Flash CS6 packages all of the local files in the root project folder or just the ones used in the app or none at all. Any information about this would be greatly appreciated as well.

```
    var FILE_LIST_PATH:String = "/25Notes/25Notes.txt";
var mp3List:Array = new Array();

LoadFile();

function LoadFile()
{
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(FILE_LIST_PATH);
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processTextFile);
    urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
}

function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent){
    trace("can't load file list:   " + e);
}


function processTextFile(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    var textFile:String = loader.data;
    mp3List = textFile.split("\n");
    for (i=0;i<mp3List.length;i++){
        trace(mp3List[i],i);
    }
}
```

Here's what the IOError trace returns:

```
can't load file list:   [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/25Notes/25Notes.txt" errorID=2032]
```

I'm totally stumped. Please help!!

Comment: Have you tried to loose first forward slash?
Have you added required file to be added to the package via: File > AIR for XXX Settings > General tab - here you have "Included files:" list to which you can add any file your application needs to have packaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file being saved by the app at runtime and you are trying to retrieve it? If not, that URL is incorrect. The `app:/` directory is the applicationStorageDirectory on the device, not a location within the app itself. You'll need to embed your txt file as a Class and access it that way

```
[Embed(source="assets/ui/images/phone/menu-myvideos-active-160.png")]
var MyVideosActive160:Class;
```

That is something from a project I am actually working on finishing right now. That embeds an image and allows me to access it afterward. To access it, I simply do

```
var bmp:Bitmap = new MyVideosActive160();
```

If you don't embed, I don't believe you can actually access the file. Every file that needs to be included within the app must be embedded.

If you are saving the file at run time at some point, you'll want to do it this way

```
var path:String = new File(new File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("/25Notes/25Notes.txt").nativePath).url;
```

That will output a `file:///` URL, rather than a url using `app:/`. I am using this method to play downloaded videos in my app. It's a crappy workaround that Adobe should have built into SDK, but that's what we have to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried using your embed idea and it worked! Is there a way to efficiently embed 25 mp3 files & put them in an array?

Comment: Same way. Create a separate `Class` for each file (no way around this, unfortunately), instantiate a new instance of that class (presumably as a `Sound` object) and push them to the array.

Comment: Oh, and just to be clear, this has absolutely nothing to do with captive run time. You would need to do the same thing with a SWF or a standard AIR app. Just keep an eye on your file size. Embedding will kill it.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 - are you sure of that: "If you don't embed, I don't believe you can actually access the file. Every file that needs to be included within the app must be embedded." - in my AIR project I have files included in the APK and I can load them without any fuss.

Comment: And another thing by embedding you increase the file size of the application and you have to publish and repackage the application when you will change anything or will want to add another file that "can't be loaded".

Comment: Yes. You must include every file that is to be used within the package. How else do you access them? There is another way, I believe, in the FlashBuilder project properties, but the Embedding using the `Class` method has the same end result. Each will will work. But each file *must* be included within the package.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz & Apocalyptic0n3! Your posts were extremely helpful! Instead of embedding each mp3 file individually I simply included the files in the APK through AIRs' publish settings in Flash CS6. And now my app is finally working on my phone! YESS!! However I am experiencing latency when playing any mp3 after its' (for lack of a better name) "play this sound object" event is called.  My captive runtime app is 8.8MB & my assets are under 1/8th of a MB. Should I be looking into caching my assets? or is there another way?